# install4j6: class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName) returns Null

Tags: java, inputstream, install4j

I am making an installer for my application using install4j.
Previously I used install4j-5 and now using install4j 6.0.1.

> Below problem is with install4j 6.0.1 & Works fine with install4j5

I am calling this from a static method

Class: Util.java
resourcePkgPath- "SysConfig.conf" File in Different Package

`public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resourcePkgPath)`
{
`return Util.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePkgPath);`
}

> When I am running my application (i.e. from installer) then it gives me NullPointerException but when I run the same application from command line then it works perfectly fine. Also it runs successfully from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the root directory to the class path of the launcher, files in it can be loaded as a resource.

In previous versions, the directory of the executable was mistakenly added to the class path by default, so that's why it used to work in your case.

If both your launcher and the "com" directory are both directly in the installation directory, add the directory "." (without the quotes) to the class path configuration of your launcher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..... I have tried but still it is not working. `inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/mmi/config/SysConfig.conf")‌​;`   Is that filepath correct??

Comment: above code is working only when that file "SysConfig.conf" is packed in jar (i.e config.jar) but in our application we don't want it to be in jar as it is configurable file so it should be out in the folder "com/mmi/config/.."   So is there any solution for this??

Comment: Then the parent directory of the "com" folder would have to be added to the class path configuration. I misunderstood your question, will edit it.

Comment: hey thank you Ingo. As you said and also referred ur other answers, I have just created **[MyLauncherName].vmoptions** file and added classpath in it.  And now without doing any code modifications it is working. Thanks